# Emacs *python-mode* apply: Spawning child process: invalid argument

Tags: python, windows, emacs

I have already install Python2.7.9, emacs-24.5,python-mode. (windows 7 32b)

1. When I use Emacs open a python file which content is: print 'hello',
   and C-c C-c or M-x py-execute-buffer, it shows *apply: Spawning child  process: invalid argument*.
2. When I run C-h k, I got：
   C-c C-c runs the command help-follow-symbol, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
   in    `help-mode.el'. It is bound to C-c C-c,  
   . (help-follow-symbol &optional POS)
3. The content of .emacs file is:

(setenv "HOME" "D:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32")
(setenv "PATH""D:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32")

;;set the default file path
(setq default-directory "~/")
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\.py$" . python-mode)    auto-mode-alist))   (setq interpreter-mode-alist (cons '("python" . 
python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist))

;;python-mode
(load   "D:/Program   Files/Emacs/emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32/site-lisp/python-mode.el")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.py'" . python-mode))   (setq
load-path (cons "D:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32/site-lisp/python-mode.el"  load-path))
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python editing mode." t)

what should i do to make emacs run python code successfully. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: M-x cmd-shell, it shows [No match]

Comment: Some of this settings don't look right. See first lines of INSTALL. Start from emacs -Q and load python-mode.el by hand to have a first impression. Than M-x python RET should open a shell for example.